# How to add data model to web api?

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core

How to add a data model to asp.net core web api?

I like to add the following model to the route:

```
 public class SomeComplexDataModel
{
    public bool DOSomething { get; set; } = false;

    public bool DoThisAndThis { get; set; } = false;

    public DateTime StartDateDaily { get; set; }

    public DateTime EndDateDaily { get; set; }

    public DateTime StartDateMonthly { get; set; }

    public DateTime EndDateMonthly { get; set; }
}
```

This is my controller code:

```
    [HttpGet("SQLite/ExcelReport/")]
    public FileResult GetExcelReport(SomeComplexDataModel someComplexDataModel)
    {
        //Some code here and returning a file
    }
```

Swagger returns this error message:

```
TypeError: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': Request with GET/HEAD method cannot have body.
```

Is it possible doing it in this way? Whats wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With that signature, it will create an action that uses the `GET` method and expects a request body to fill in that `SomeComplexDataModel` by default. You cannot pass parameters in the body of a `GET` method.

A simple way to fix this would be to change the method that allows passing a request body, `POST` would be sufficient in this case.

---

However if it makes sense to make this a `GET` action, you need to instruct it to pass the parameters in a different way. Judging by the name of the route and properties on the object, you could tell it to expect the properties as query parameters. Just apply the `[FromQuery]` attribute to the parameter.

```
[HttpGet("SQLite/ExcelReport/")]
public FileResult GetExcelReport([FromQuery] SomeComplexDataModel someComplexDataModel)
{
    //Some code here and returning a file
}
```

Each property of the model would then be mapped to a query parameter of the same name. Though I would suggest making all your properties nullable so you can detect the omission of a parameter.

Comment: [FromQuery] is the solution for this get method. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You should change HttpGet to HttpPost !

The HTTP GET method is for requesting a representation of the specified resource. Requests using GET should only retrieve data and hence cannot have body.